# How to create a "non-dynamic" Guid as value for a database entry?

Tags: c#, guid

I'll try to explain what I'd like to obtain:
I'm trying to create a Guid value as an attribute of my database entry.
I've already checked other questions and answers to resolve my issue and this is the Model I got so far:

```
public class MyModel
{
    private Guid myGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid MyGuid
    {
        get { return myGuid; }
        set { myGuid = value; }
    }
}
```

But the issue isn't in this code. Because in this way, the Guid value is automatically generated and I'm able to verify the Guid in my Views.
But every time I edit an entry in my DB the Guid is kinda refreshing itself and change. That's why I called it "dynamic" Guid.
I guess because the attribute **MyGuid** recall every time the private part of the data model (**= Guid.NewGuid();**).
So how could I create a random Guid and later set it as value of MyGuid?

***EDIT-1***

I created a method in my Model in order to create a more precise Guid generation. Now my model looks like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string myGuid = Convert.ToString(new Guid());

    public string MyMethod(string myValue)
    {
        var empty = Convert.ToString(new Guid());
        if (myValue == null || myValue == empty)
        {
            var newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string stringGuid = Convert.ToString(newGuid);
            return stringGuid;
        }
        else { return myValue;}
    }

    public Guid MyGuid
    {
        get { return myGuid; }
        set { myGuid = MyMethod(value); }
    }
}
```

This method worked only once, during a test on another project, and then, when I tried to import this method, it broke and stopped working.
Using this method, when I create an entry in my database, it should generate a Guid.NewGuid() every time my Guid editor field is empty or have a zero Guid, isn't it?
So, why this code is working on a side project and it's not working on another one?
What am I missing?

Comment: Why not set it in the constructor?

Comment: You're likely not populating MyGuid properly from the database when loading `MyModel`.  The `NewGuid` would happen as part of the object construction, after which it should be overridden with your DB value -- assuming you're properly loading it!  If you ARE loading it properly, then my guess is you're not storing it as a hidden value in the `View` so when posting back it thinks you're creating a new record instead of editing an existing one.  Without more context, just a hunch.

Comment: If you're writing the Guid to the database and you want to read it back from the database, you have to populate the model with the value from the database somehow.  Currently all the code shows is that you create a new Guid every time you create an instance of the model.

Comment: threating `Guid` as string isn't really a good idea. Your class deal with `Guid`, threat them as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep something more close to the first model IMHO.

You could simply add a constructor with the Guid as parameter

```
public class MyModel
{
    private Guid myGuid;

    public MyModel()
    {
        myGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public MyModel(Guid guid)
    {
        myGuid = guid;
    }

    public Guid MyGuid
    {
        get { return myGuid; }
        set { myGuid = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But it keeps on not returning a new Guid each time I create an entry...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a GUID in code you can create it in database as well only at the time of insertion like this

```
          DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier
          SET @ID = NEWID()
```